# How do I make a custom build tool execute before the compiler runs in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, custom-build-step

I have a custom tool I need to run before a build in Visual Studio 2008. The tool generates C++ code based on custom input files, therefore I need it to run *before* Visual Studio starts compiling the C++.

I have it set up with a custom build rule, and it mostly works, however, the build process doesn't seem to wait until the tool is completed, leading to the need to rebuild after building with changes to my input files. This is either because Visual Studio doesn't recognize the changed files until after the build is complete, or it starts the build before the tool is finished running. I'm not sure which is the case.

So the problem is:
 
1. I trigger a build.
2. Custom tool runs.
3. Build starts
4. Build completes before output from step 2 is available. 
5. I need to trigger another build to include the generated changes.

I would very much like to have step 3 just wait for step 2.

Comment: Have you added the automatically generated files to the project or are they just cluttering up the disk as far as VS is concerned?

Comment: I've tried both. Doesn't change anything.